# Количество строк во всех таблицах

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть БД с несколькими тысячами таблиц (Oracle если это важно). Список таблиц получаю запросом:

```
 select table_name from all_tables;
```

По каждой таблице могу получить количество записей:

```
 select count(*) as numRecords from <table_name>;
```

Теперь, нужно получить количества записей во всех таблицах - что-то типа:

```
 <table_name> <numRecords>
```

Как это сделать не привлекая PL/SQL - простым SQL?

Comment: Не забудте посмотреть [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615733/6571020) как дополнение к принятому ответу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В all_tables всё есть. Во всяком случае на 11g.

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows FROM all_tables;
```

Вопрос дублируется, на английском стэке [есть несколько ответов на этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704808/get-counts-of-all-tables-in-a-schema) как с PL/SQL, так и без.